# Rails: remote authentication through devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, bcrypt-ruby

Let's say I have a default user authorization through devise in my rails app (using the default `bcrypt` encryptor).

I'm trying to make something like gui application, when user can sign in using rails application password. But I don't want to send my password to user application through ajax (it's insecure in my opinion). Is there any common way for remote authentication to devise using hashes?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

[Token based authentication for Devise](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth)
[Devise comes with OmniAuth support out of the box](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview)

[Or you can try to implement yourself](http://4trabes.com/2012/10/31/remote-authentication-with-devise/)

Comment: Hey!

I can't understand how to use `omniauth` in this keys.